# How to check whether any elements of a list exist in an arrayfield in django?

Tags: python, django

I have list of table ids and I want to check if any of those ids occur in an array-field column.

`myList = [2,3]`
database column has values for example: `[1]`, `[1,4,3]`, `[1,2,3,4]`, `[2,3]`

I have a column in the db which is an arrayfield containing a list of ids from another table. I want to query this field and check if any elements in my list are in any rows of this column.

I want to query this column and return those rows which have any occurrence of 2 or 3.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should try [overlap](https://docs.djangoproject.com/fr/2.2/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/#overlap):

`MyObject.objects.filter(listOfIds__overlap=myList)`